# URL masking redirect works only on the landing page. How to make it work on internal pages?

Tags: subdomain, godaddy, amazon-aws, domain-forwarding

My content is hosted on elastic beanstalk and the domain is bought from Godaddy.

I want my staging.domain.com/* to redirect to elastic-beanstalk-url/*.

I am doing a redirect on the Godaddy UI which masks elastic-beanstalk-url  to staging.domain.com but any internal page such elastic-beanstalk-url/foo is shown unmasked.

How can i achieve elastic-beanstalk-url/foo being masked to staging.domain.com/foo for all values of foo?

Comment: GoDaddy's _Forward with Masking_ will insert the forwarded site into an _iframe_, thus paths will not be preserved. To preserve paths, you'll need to select just the _Forwarding_ option (without masking), however, this will _redirect_ and not mask the URL.

Comment: Instead you can migrate your DNS from GoDaddy to [Amazon Route 53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html) so that you can use your domain registered with GoDaddy as a custom domain for AWS Elastic Beanstalk. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602232/how-to-link-godaddy-domain-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment) question should help with that.

Comment: @dan Would you mind adding that as an answer? I would love to accept it, it really helped!

Comment: Feel free to copy it into an answer (and embellish it a bit if you like), then you'll be able to accept it in a day and earn some rep here :-)